# Troubleshoot instant freeze after login on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, xorg, intel, crash, intel-nuc

On a clean Ubuntu 16.04 desktop install, I'm encountering total system freeze (tty+ssh down) as soon as I login (during the fade animation). The system is a recent Intel NuC (Nuc6i5) with a Skylake processor. Looks like the GPU is crashing somehow.

I'm trying to troubleshoot the issue but I can't find anything valuable in the logs. So far I've looked at:

- `/var/log/syslog`
- `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`

I can grasp the last moments of `/var/log/syslog` with SSH:

```
May 19 18:15:26 player systemd[1]: Started Session c2 of user carlipa.
May 19 18:15:26 player org.ayatana.bamf[1780]: bamfdaemon start/running, process 1838
May 19 18:15:26 player org.a11y.Bus[1780]: ** (process:1861): WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
May 19 18:15:26 player org.a11y.Bus[1780]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
May 19 18:15:26 player org.a11y.Bus[1780]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
May 19 18:15:26 player org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1868]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
May 19 18:15:27 player dbus[905]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' unit='upower.service'
May 19 18:15:27 player systemd[1]: Starting Daemon for power management...
May 19 18:15:27 player dbus[905]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UPower'
May 19 18:15:27 player systemd[1]: Started Daemon for power management.
May 19 18:15:27 player rtkit-daemon[1451]: Successfully made thread 2057 of process 2057 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
May 19 18:15:27 player rtkit-daemon[1451]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
May 19 18:15:27 player org.gnome.ScreenSaver[1780]: ** (gnome-screensaver:2006): WARNING **: Couldn't get presence status: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
May 19 18:15:27 player gnome-session[1917]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
May 19 18:15:27 player gnome-session[1917]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
May 19 18:15:27 player gnome-session[1917]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
May 19 18:15:27 player org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5[1780]: ** Failed to load key file at 'file:///home/carlipa/.config/evolution/sources/system-proxy.source': Data source is missing a [Data Source] group
May 19 18:15:27 player rtkit-daemon[1451]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
May 19 18:15:27 player rtkit-daemon[1451]: Successfully made thread 2083 of process 2057 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
May 19 18:15:27 player rtkit-daemon[1451]: Supervising 5 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
May 19 18:15:27 player rtkit-daemon[1451]: Supervising 5 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
May 19 18:15:27 player rtkit-daemon[1451]: Successfully made thread 2084 of process 2057 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
May 19 18:15:27 player rtkit-daemon[1451]: Supervising 6 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
May 19 18:15:27 player bluetoothd[890]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.65 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
May 19 18:15:27 player bluetoothd[890]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.65 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
May 19 18:15:27 player dbus[905]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service'
May 19 18:15:27 player pulseaudio[2057]: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
May 19 18:15:27 player bluetoothd[890]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
May 19 18:15:27 player systemd[1]: Starting Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
May 19 18:15:27 player rtkit-daemon[1451]: Successfully made thread 2087 of process 2087 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
May 19 18:15:27 player rtkit-daemon[1451]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.
May 19 18:15:27 player pulseaudio[2087]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
May 19 18:15:27 player dbus[905]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.ColorManager'
May 19 18:15:27 player systemd[1]: Started Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles.
May 19 18:15:28 player gnome-session[1917]: (process:2107): indicator-application-service-WARNING **: Name Lost
May 19 18:15:28 player gnome-session-binary[1917]: Entering running state
May 19 18:15:28 player dbus[905]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.locale1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.locale1.service'
May 19 18:15:28 player systemd[1]: Starting Locale Service...
May 19 18:15:28 player dbus[905]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.UDisks2' unit='udisks2.service'
May 19 18:15:28 player systemd[1]: Starting Disk Manager...
May 19 18:15:28 player udisksd[2138]: udisks daemon version 2.1.7 starting
May 19 18:15:28 player gnome-session[1917]: (gnome-software:2110): Gs-WARNING **: failed to open plugin /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
May 19 18:15:28 player dbus[905]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2'
May 19 18:15:28 player systemd[1]: Started Disk Manager.
May 19 18:15:28 player udisksd[2138]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
May 19 18:15:28 player dbus[905]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.locale1'
May 19 18:15:28 player systemd[1]: Started Locale Service.
May 19 18:15:28 player org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor[1780]: Volume monitor alive
May 19 18:15:28 player gnome-session[1917]: (gnome-software:2110): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
May 19 18:15:28 player gnome-session[1917]: (gnome-software:2110): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
May 19 18:15:28 player dbus[905]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.fwupd' (using servicehelper)
May 19 18:15:28 player udisksd[2138]: Mounted /dev/mmcblk0p2 at /media/carlipa/PI_ROOT on behalf of uid 1000
May 19 18:15:28 player kernel: [  106.237017] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
May 19 18:15:28 player udisksd[2138]: Mounted /dev/mmcblk0p1 at /media/carlipa/PI_BOOT on behalf of uid 1000
May 19 18:15:28 player org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar7[1780]: (evolution-calendar-factory-subprocess:2206): libedata-cal-CRITICAL **: e_intervaltree_destroy: assertion 'E_IS_INTERVALTREE (tree)' failed
May 19 18:15:28 player org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar7[1780]: (evolution-calendar-factory-subprocess:2206): libedata-cal-CRITICAL **: e_intervaltree_destroy: assertion 'E_IS_INTERVALTREE (tree)' failed
May 19 18:15:29 player org.gnome.ScreenSaver[1780]: ** Message: Lost the name, shutting down.
May 19 18:15:29 player dbus[905]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd'
Connection to 192.168.0.175 closed.
```

What else can I do to troubleshoot this issue?